# Is there any way to get the output of PHP array like it's defined

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array like this

```
$array = ['a','b','c','d']
```

Now in order to see it on screen, i have two options:

`var_dump` or `print_r`

But their output is like

`Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d )`

or

`array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" [3]=> string(1) "d" }`

I sometimes find it difficult to read.

Is there any way to get the output like

`['a','b','c','d']`

so that it's easy to read?

Comment: @Barmar, He exactly wants it like that(how the array was constructed) and `var_export` wont do that. He wants that for reading purposes.

Comment: I concur with @Barmar - if you want to print actual PHP code then use `var_export`. You can assign the value to a variable instead of printing it if you pass `true` as the second argument, which is sometimes useful. Of course, the 5.4 short array syntax is sugar, what `var_export` will give you is the old `array()` style output. But that's readable too right? Alternatively, if you find the output of `var_dump` hard to read, I'd highly recommend XDebug which will nicely format your `var_dump` output: http://oi60.tinypic.com/1o84ex.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are needing it for reading purposes.. for that make use of `json_encode()`;

```
<?php
$array = ['a','b','c','d'];
echo json_encode($array);  //"prints" ["a","b","c","d"]
```

Comment: json is not really optimal for reading purpose.. try to encode an multi-dim array and read the output..

Comment: @Philipp, Ikr. Weird questions do have weird answers.

Comment: @Philipp I don't think he's worried about that. He wants to stop simple arrays from being printed in complex notation. If he has a complex array, he should use `var_dump` or `print_r`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own function:

```
function print_array($array) {
   echo '[';
   foreach($array as $letter) {
      echo $letter . ',';
   }
   echo ']';
}

$arr = ['a','b','c','d'];
print_array($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
    <pre></pre>
```

tag before and after print_r function and suparet them

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($array,1)."</pre>";
```

Comment: This is not printing result what OP is wanting. He is already tried print_r.

Comment: No but the formatting is good for reading... and thats basically what he is asking for.

Comment: He said this: *Is there any way to get the output like ['a','b','c','d']...* He wants to display the array in that format.

Comment: I still don't agree :) The user is asking for a readable format. Not knowing that he cant get the by using the code I provided. Its not a matter of format. That was the suggestion by him self. My answer is still solving the core issue readability. Even @Philipp answered two minutes after with the same answer.. But okay that's your take on it :)

Answer (score -1):

The output of `var_dump` or `print_r` is readable - the problem is the html output, which removes line-breaks.

So I suggest to use this functions inside a pre-tag

```
echo '<pre><code>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</code></pre>';
```

Also you could install the php module xdebug which could modify the output of var_dump for better readability: http://xdebug.org/docs/display